# Get-PnPFolderItem is always returning "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold."

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have the following script to get all root folders (we have 5.5 K) inside a document library:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Folders=Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderSiteRelativeURL  -ItemType Folder | Where {$_.Name -ne "Forms"}
```

But it will raise this exception:-

```
Get-PnPFolderItem : The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.
At line:1 char:10
+ $Folders=Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderSiteRelative ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPFolderItem], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.GetFolderItem
```

so how i can get the items in batches? as seems the Get-PnPFolderItem does not have a row limit or page size parameters?

Comment: Do you have more than 5K items in root folder of document library or total more than 5K items because that comments worked from me where I do have only three root folders in my document library and each folder contains 3k documents so in total I tried with 6k documents?

Comment: @Kalpesh Vaghela yes i have more than 5 k root folders as i mentioned